# lcsv file line replace

Tags: java

I am creating a csv file as follows:

```
public class check
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   generateCsvFile("/RMT/test.csv"); 
}

private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName)
{
try
{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName,false);

    writer.write("DisplayName");
    writer.write(',');
    writer.write("Age");
    writer.write('\n');

    writer.write("MKYONG");
    writer.write(',');
    writer.write("26");

    writer.write("YOUR NAME");
    writer.write(',');
    writer.write("29");

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
} 
}
```

Here I am writing two lines in the file, but when I am writing the second line I want to replace the first line (the header) rather than append it. How can i do it? Can some help me?

Comment: actually in my project it was required to print the avg ,max ,min bytes read into the csv file ...i will be calculating those values for every 10 seconds ...but at the end i want only final result ...so i just want to replace that line every time so that in the end i get the  total avg ,max and min

Comment: why can't you do the calculation in memory and write to file only once?

Comment: actually the process will be stopped by another process but we dont when it will be stopped !! so we need to writeee data to the file ....

Comment: You should to use [`open CSV`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) to read and write CSV files. It would make your task of reading and writing (and other) CSV files easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the csv data into memory and do the calculation, then write the result to the file.

if it won't work for you somehow:

- you could load the file you are gonna write to, and read the 1st line( header), then append new calculated datasets (in memory),  overwrite the file.
- if the header is fixed text, then save it as a variable then you don't need to load the header from the file.
- if you need operate the file precisely, check out  java.io.RandomAccessFile

Comment: you keep the file open and do writing, it won't overwrite the file. you could either close  after each writing. or keep it open and get the offset, write new data at the offset. then the old content will be overwritten.